# Parsing a string into a dictionary with two keys and a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python program prog1 (mapper) printing out below in three fields.  It ends with

```
 print user, text, rt
```

First field is username.  Second is tweet text.  Third is # of retweets.  Trying to figure out TopN retweets

Below is an example

```
inocybetech RT @ONAPproject: #ONAPAmsterdam is here! This first code release delivers a unified architecture for end-to-end, closed-loop…  5
jchawki RT @ONAPproject: #ONAPAmsterdam is here! This first code release delivers a unified architecture for end-to-end, closed-loop…  6
jchawki RT @opnfv: Congrats to @ONAPproject on Amsterdam, on its 1st platform release! Learn more about its unified architecture for e…  2
jchawki RT @jzemlin: Now Available! #ONAP Amsterdam brings globally shared implementation for network automation, based on OSS &amp; open st…  3
jchawki RT @bdwick: Now Available! #ONAP Amsterdam brings globally shared implementation for network automation, based on OSS &amp; open st…  1
```

I am piping this into another Python program prog2 (reducer) via stdin.  My problem is figuring out how to read this into a dictionary with two Keys (user and text) and the value (retweet)

If I say

```
for line in sys.stdin
```

line is not capturing the entire string.  What I need to do is capture the three fields in a dictionary with two keys and one value.

Can you suggest something? I am just starting to learn Python

Thanks

Comment: What is output for `for line in sys.stdin:` `print line` ?

Comment: If Prog1 has print (user, text, rt), the output from this script  is u'user', u'text', rt.  When I print line in Prog2 after "for line in sys.stdin", I get [u'user', u'text',rt].  type(line) says str and len(line) says 150+ characters.  It would be nice to get Prog2 to read the output of Prog1 as list with three entries.  Don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to use a format which is easier for parsing. If you print everything just space-delimited, it might get quite complicated to separate individual fields afterwards since the text of the tweet contains spaces (and perhaps even newlines).

One option would be to generate/parse CSV (this has the additional advantage that you can use your output easily with other software supporting CSV input).

So the writer (`csvw.py`) could in loose terms look like:

```
import csv
import sys

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter = ' ')

writer.writerow(['Name', 'Content\nof the message', 12])
```

and the reader (`csvr.py`):

```
import csv
import sys

reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter = ' ')
stat = {}
for record in reader:
    name, message, cnt = record

    key = (name, message)
    stat[key] = int(cnt)

print(stat)
```

then if you do:

```
python csvw.py | python csvr.py
```

you get:

```
{('Name', 'Content\nof the message'): 12}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I tried this and getting an error "Too many values to unpack"

Comment: With the delimiter of '_', it seems to be working.  Fingers crossed.. Thanks